# ¿Qué sería lo que tengo mal en este código que no me devuelve lo que espero?

Tags: python

Tengo un código de python el cual debe de pasar de binario a decimal y viceversa, el tema es que quiero poner una condición antes de que haga la cuenta de binario a decimal, la cual es que si entra un número que obtenga un número diferente de 0 o 1 de un error y deje volver a poner el número binario, pero no entiendo por que me funciona mal, pongo un 0 o un 1 y entra a la condición de "validación", desde ya muchas gracias cracks.

```
def decimal_a_binario(decimal):
    if decimal == 0:
      return "El número en binario es 0"
    else:
      binario = ""
      while decimal > 0:
        resto = decimal % 2
        binario = str(resto) + binario
        decimal //= 2
        
      return binario
def binario_a_decimal(binario):
  decimal = 0
  posicion = 0
  while binario > 0:
    digito = binario % 10
    decimal += digito * (2 ** posicion)
    binario //= 10
    posicion += 1 
  return decimal

while True:
  mensaje = int(input("Escribe 0 si quieres convertir de decimal a binario, 1 si quieres convertir de binario a decimal o 2 para salir:\n"))
  if mensaje == 0:
    numero_decimal = int(input("Escribe el número en decimal que quieras convertir a binario:\n"))
    numero_binario = decimal_a_binario(numero_decimal)
    print(f"El número decimal: {numero_decimal} en binario es: {numero_binario}")
  elif mensaje == 1:
    numero_binario = input("Escribe el número binario que quieras convertir a decimal\n")
    validacion = False
    for i in numero_binario:
      if i != 0 or i != 1:
        validacion = True
        break
      else:
        None
    if validacion == True:
         print("Error, ingresaste un número en decimal, quizás deberias elegir el número 0, vuelve a intentarlo :D\n")
    else:
       numero_decimal = binario_a_decimal (int(numero_binario))
       print(f"El número binario: {numero_binario} en decimal es: {numero_decimal}")
  elif mensaje == 2:
    print("Chau! :)")
    break
  else:
    print("Error, el número que ingresaste es incorrecto, debes ingresar 0 para convertir de decimal a binario o 1 para convertir de binario a decimal.")
```

Comment: Tu error es querer comprar un número con un string (`mensaje`).

Comment: El código debe ir en texto (no en imagen) para poder reproducirlo y hacer las pruebas pertinentes. Por otro lado, el fragmento de código está incompleto.

Comment: if i != 0 or i != 1: no es or.. es AND... porque si no.. ingresas 1, y 1 es distinto de 0, entonces entro... o 0, es distinto de 1, entonces entro...

Comment: La forma de indicar que una respuesta solucionó el problema (y de paso agradecer al autor de la respuesta) es marcar la respuesta como la mejor (lo podés hacer presionando la tilde). Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de aclarar que fue solucionado :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay 2 problemas en está línea:

```py
if i != 0 or i != 1:
```

(1) Estás comprando una cadena `'1'` o `'0'` contra un número `1` o `0`. Así que ese `if` siempre dará `True`.

(2) En un `or`, se evalúa `True` inmediatamente donde se encuentre una condición verdadera, ignorando las demás, entonces:

Por ejemplo:

Para `i = '1'` --> `if i != '0'` ¡verdadero!, entrará al bloque
Para `i = '0'` --> `if i != '1'` ¡verdadero!, entrará al bloque
Para `i = '3'` --> `if i != '0'` ¡verdadero!, entrará al bloque

En cualquier caso entrará al `if`, resultando el mensaje que siempre ves.

Solución: Si bien, la *lógica negativa* suele ser elegante, algunas veces confunde a los más nuevos. Si lo cambias a *lógica positiva* se entiende más:

```py
    # ...
    validacion = True # <-- Se cambió a True
    for i in numero_binario:
      if i == '0' or i == '1': # <-- Cambio
        validacion = False # <-- cambió a False
        break
      else:
        pass #None <-- Usar pass en vez de None si no se va hacer nada
    # ...
```

Otra solución es dejando todo el código tal cual, y solo cambiando la línea problemática por:

```py
if i not in ['0', '1']:
```

Comment: Ahí pude arreglarlo, muchisimas gracias <3, es necesario que borre mi pregunta?